# routes.rb file not routing as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a system of nested categories, which are dealt with in the routes.rb file as following:

```
path = "/categories/:id"
10.times do |i|
    path << "/:id#{i}"
    match path => "categories#show", :via => [:get]
end
```

This all works very well.

The problem is that I have a couple of cases where I don't want to use my generic categories#show page. For example for one category I want to fire to a completely different controller entirely.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
  # Override certain category page
  match "categories/MyCategory" => "othercontroller#specialcase"


  path = "/categories/:id"
  10.times do |i|
    path << "/:id#{i}"
    match path => "categories#show", :via => [:get]
  end
```

I thought that by doing this any request for exactly "www.myurl.com/categories/MyCategory would instead be passed to `othercontroller` instead of `categories`. This doesn't seem to be the case though.

Can anybody explain why? I thought priority was based on file order.

Comment: Is your categories/MyCategory actually defined before your categories/:id?

Comment: I don't understand your comment? It is defined exactly as in the second code sample.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek, could you clarify?

Comment: I was just thinking that if it was defined elsewhere in the file, then when Rails is looking for a route, it finds categories/:id before categories/MyCategory. But if its defined as here, that wouldn't be the case. But as I look at it, I see you never define categories/:id anyway. Perhaps there is something elsewhere in your routes which matches before this?

Comment: @JoshuaCheek, it turns out the problem was between my keyboard and my chair. Of course you are write, and the resource declaration was above the special case. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had such cases before, it seems that Rails could confuse the string "MyCategory" for an ID in your other route.

I would do something like this:

```
match "categories/special/MyCategory" => "othercontroller#specialcase"

path = "/categories/:id"
10.times do |i|
    path << "/:id#{i}"
    match path => "categories#show", :via => [:get]
end
```

In short, make sure you don't have a path entry that ends like a parameter in another route (in your example, "MyCategory" = ":id"). I have never been able to find an explicit warning in the Rails docs, but practice teaches best.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: But that is the thing, the whole point is that for certain categories the special case is fired, I don't want to be changing the URL structure. I can technically do this in the categories controller, but I was hoping to be able to use routes.

Comment: I'm accepting this as it got me thinking along the right lines. Actual problem was having another route further up the file that was confusing things,.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. =)